# How to change Android emulator ( ldplayer, noxplayer etc...) boot animation

Tags: c#, android, automation, emulation

I want to change background when I start up LDPlayer. Can someone help me?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Cool image, but it doesn´t show **any** question nor any code nor any information at all. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want to change background when I start up LDPlayer. pls

Comment: For questions other than development or programming, but related to the Android framework, use this link: https://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I download [NoxPlayer](https://www.bignox.com/) and can change the background easily on the right upper corner of the emulator. You can try it.